# Column formatting - add style on top of existing styles

Tags: sharepoint-online, column-formatting, formatting

I have a "person" column in one of my lists which allows multiple selections. I would like to format it so that all the pills are displayed as flex with wrap enabled.

I'm looking for a simple way to **add style on top of the existing styles**.

In the below screenshot for "Desired View" the only style that I added in Browser devtools is this:

```css
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

| Existing/Default View | Expected/Desired View |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Default view of Person column] | [image: Desired output view of Person column] |

- I found a [similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275056/formatting-multiple-values-in-people-and-group-fields-on-sharepoint-online-with), but the solution provided there was to use JSON formatting to re-structure the entire DOM of the `gridCell`
- I found an article which describes [how to format a persons column](https://tutorialsinhand.com/Articles/sharepoint-column-formatting-person-field.aspx) but this also describes structuring the entire contents from scratch.

Comment: Column Formatting is all or none. You can either control the rendering of the entire field or none of it. So to add those styles you would have to recreate the format with your styles included.